# Visual Studio 2015 Mobile Cross Platform

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, cross-platform, visual-studio-2015

with the new release of visual studio 2015 Preview, is there any possibility that the newest visual studio allow us to develop mobile cross platform (iOS, android, wp8...) with using .NET language C# or VB.NET?

Refer to this article:
http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/11/visual-studio-2015-goes-even-more-cross-platform-with-clang-android-emulator/

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio mobile cross platform use Apache Cordova (HTML5), but you can use C# (no VB.Net) with Xamarin (in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio with Xamarin integration)

Answer (score 1):

It seems visual studio 2015 supports cross platform development very well, it even support android native activity c++ project and native debug like developing for windows.

you can check this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQ_CuCKJRIs

it is just too good to be true, amazing!